# Enable remote desktop control in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, gnome, ssh, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a clean installation of Ubuntu 22.04 on a remote machine that I can reach only via ssh (I have no physical access).
I want to enable the remote desktop protocol (RDP).
In [this article](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/ubuntu-22-04-remote-desktop-control/) the procedure seems simple: open `Gnome Settings > Sharing` and enable `Remote Desktop` and `Remote Control`; unfortunately it requires to use the Gnome GUI that I can not access.
Looking around the web I found that this commands

```bsh
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.vnc view-only false
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.vnc auth-method 'password'
$ systemctl --user start gnome-remote-desktop
$ systemctl --user status gnome-remote-desktop
● gnome-remote-desktop.service - GNOME Remote Desktop
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-remote-desktop.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-05-19 13:41:30 CEST; 11s ago
   Main PID: 50884 (gnome-remote-de)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 2205)
     Memory: 21.9M
        CPU: 36ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/gnome-remote-desktop.service
             └─50884 /usr/libexec/gnome-remote-desktop-daemon

mag 19 13:41:30 **OMISSIS** systemd[50403]: Starting GNOME Remote Desktop...
mag 19 13:41:30 **OMISSIS** systemd[50403]: Started GNOME Remote Desktop.
```

should be part of the solution, however they are not enough as I still can not connect to the remote machine using my remote desktop client (I am using Microsoft Remote Desktop from a late 2011 Mackbook pro running MacOS 10.13.6). The error I get is:

```
Unable to connect

We couldn't connect to the remote PC. Make sure the PC is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

Error code: 0x204
```

I suppose I still have to do something on the remote machine.

Comment: As an aside, you can also look into [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/?pli=1).  I haven't tried it myself, but know that it exists...  I think a Chrome instance has to be running on the server.

Comment: @user68186 is there a way to avoid new packages and use the already installed tools?

Comment: I tried it on a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a VM. The solution in your link didn't not work before `xrdp` was installed.

Comment: Yes, I managed to login into Gnome after installing `xrdp`, but the graphic is extremely slow. Any hint?

Comment: @Sirion I am not familiar with either Microsoft Remote Desktop or the MacOS. You may have to change settings in the RDP client.